# Как сделать echo команду с указанием канала, в который бот оправит текст?

Tags: python

Как сделать echo команду с указанием канала, **в который бот оправит текст?**
Например: **m.echo #канал "текст"**.

Помогите пожалуйста.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def megaecho(ctx, channel: channel.id, arg1 = None, arg2 = None):
    if arg1 == None:
        await ctx.send("Вы не ввели заголовок сообщения!")
        return
    if arg2 == None:
        await ctx.send("Вы не ввели текст сообщения!")
        return
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=arg1,
            description=arg2,
            colour=discord.Colour.green()
        )
        await client.get_channel(channel).send(
            embed = embed
        )
```

**Я там убрал много всего, я просто текстовый аргумент делал как указывание канала.**

Comment: Я гуглил везде, я слепой наверное

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего так.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def megaecho(ctx, channel_id: int, title: str = None, text: str = None):
    if not channel_id:
        await ctx.send("Вы не ввели id канала!")
        return
    if not title:
        await ctx.send("Вы не ввели заголовок сообщения!")
        return
    if not text:
        await ctx.send("Вы не ввели текст сообщения!")
        return
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=title,
            description=text,
            color=discord.Colour.green()
        )
        
        await client.get_channel(channel_id).send(embed=embed)
```